# How do I retrieve data inside the $value parameter for Laravel Validation Closures?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am using the Laravel Closure for a one off custom validaton.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'file' => [
   'required',
   'file',
   'max:5000',
    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
    //dd($value);
    //dd($value[mimeType]);
    //dd($value["mimeType"]);
    //dd($value->mimeType);
    },
 ],
]);
```

I want to run a check on some the values in *$value*.

When I *dd($value)* I get:

> UploadedFile {#200 ▼
>
> -originalName: "lb1.mp4"
>
> -mimeType: "video/mp4"
>
> #hashName: null
>
> path: "/private/var/folders/lh/cjcr6_bs2m145w73bjgykl7c0000gn/T"
>
> filename: "phpn10jdF"
>
> basename: "phpn10jdF"

I am trying to get the *mimeType*.

I have tried:

```
dd($value[mimeType]);
dd($value["mimeType"]);
dd($value->mimeType);
```

The above is not working.

How do I retrieve data inside the $value parameter for Laravel Validation Closures?

Comment: Have you tried `$value->getClientMimeType()`?

Comment: Check the laravel doc about UploadedFile https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html

Comment: @HCK, This works and is easiest solution

Comment: @seamus are you referring tyo what I commented out? Please, confirm it to post it as a proper answer :)